# Java String to Date Conversions to print 1 year of Dates

Tags: java, datetime

**Code**
I have to get all dates for the past year start from the sDate1 string.
This is code going nowhere right now but just added it, hope someone can help. There are string to LocalDateTime, Date to LocalDateTime error arising which I am not able to solve and its stuck

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");  
String Date = "20181120";
Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(sDate1);

LocalDateTime start =LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime end = start.minusYears (1);
List<String> First = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> Second = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> Third = new ArrayList<>();
while (!end.isAfter(start)) {
    First.add(dtf.format(end)+"_*_A.dat");
    Second.add(dtf.format(end)+"_*_B.dat");
    Third.add(dtf.format(end)+"_*_C.dat");
    end = end.plusDays(1);
}
```

Comment: Personally, I might use `end.isBefore(start)` as its a little easier to understand

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are written in camelCase – the first letter being lowercase.

Comment: @MadProgrammer But the meaning will not be the same in case `end` and `start` are the same date. So when the inclusive range is wanted, `!end.isAfter(start)` is right.

Comment: @OleV.V. Sure, add `equals` to the equation - I'm just saying it's easier to read as it doesn't need a reader to reverse the logic - because I be smart :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I thought your own code was good enough to go into an answer.
2. I also though Basil Bourque’s suggestion of a stream was good enough to be spelled out a little more.

### Your own answer

The code you posted in a comment is quite unreadable, of course. Here I have formatted it (or my Eclipse has):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    String sDate1 = "20181120";
    LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(sDate1, dtf);
    LocalDate end = date1.plusYears(1);
    ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> third = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!date1.isAfter(end)) {
        first.add(dtf.format(date1) + "*_A.dat");
        second.add(dtf.format(date1) + "_B.dat");
        third.add(dtf.format(date1) + "__C.dat");
        date1 = date1.plusDays(1);
    }

    // Let’s also see some of the result
    first.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output, abbreviated:

> ```
> 20181120*_A.dat
> 20181121*_A.dat
> 20181122*_A.dat
> 20181123*_A.dat
> …
> 20191118*_A.dat
> 20191119*_A.dat
> 20191120*_A.dat
> ```

To sum up the changes from the question:

- You needed to parse the date string to get a start date. However there was no reason to bring in the troublesome and outdated `SimpleDateFormat` for that. java.time provides all the functionality we need.
- Since we only need a date, not the time of day, there was also no reason to use `LocalDateTime`.
- You probably still intended `_*_` in front of each of `A`, `B` and `C`, but you can fix that yourself.

### Use a stream

```
    List<String> first = date1.datesUntil(end.plusDays(1))
            .map(d -> d.format(dtf) + "_*_A.dat")
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this case I recommend three separate stream pipelines for the three lists. Since the `datesUntil` method accepts an *exclusive* end date and you want your end date included, we need to add 1 day.

Answer (score 4):

## Stream

[Java 9 and later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) added the [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-) method to generate a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ; 
Stream< LocalDate > stream = today.minusYears( 1 ).datesUntil( today ) ;
```

Loop through that stream.

```
stream.forEach( ( LocalDate localDate ) -> {
    System.out.println( localDate );
} );
```

> 2017-12-01
>
> 2017-12-02
>
> 2017-12-03
>
> …

For more info on streams, see [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) and the articles, [*Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) and [*Part 2*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2-2227132.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your specific task. But here is what I would write:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");  
String sDate1 = "20181120";
LocalDate date1= LocalDate.parse(sDate1, dtf);

LocalDate start = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate end = start.plusYears(1);
ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> third = new ArrayList<>();
while (!start.isAfter(end)) {
    first.add(dtf.format(start)+"_*_A.dat");
    second.add(dtf.format(start)+"_*_B.dat");
    third.add(dtf.format(start)+"_*_C.dat");
    start = start.plusDays(1);
}
```

Comment: DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");  
String sDate1 = "20181120";
LocalDate date1= LocalDate.parse(sDate1, dtf);

LocalDate end = date1.plusYears(1);
ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> third = new ArrayList<>();
while (!date1.isAfter(end)) {
    first.add(dtf.format(date1)+"_*_A.dat");
    second.add(dtf.format(date1)+"_*_B.dat");
    third.add(dtf.format(date1)+"_*_C.dat");
    date1 = date1.plusDays(1);
}

Comment: I was using localdatetime which caused problems thanks for helping with that. You can edit you answer if you want.

Comment: @th0rben, thanks for providing the answer that was helpful to the asker. However, to helpful to other readers too (and even more helpful to the asker) I recommend adding explanation of how this solves the problems in the question.